# Div not full width/height because of scroll-less scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, frontend

The selected child and it's parent and html/body all height/width 100% and padding right/bottom 0 (or at least I have tried that).

These bottom and right bars appear once a month and it drives me nuts. They are the exact same width as scroll bars, yet appear empty (without a dark scroll oval).

[image]

Comment: could you explain more ?

Comment: this is usually due to overflow:scroll. if that is the case, change it to overflow:auto. i am just guessing because there is not enough information

Comment: @Binbo thanks man! there was an `overflow:scroll` in a parent template

Comment: @Binbo if you want to add an answer with a bit of info on why overflow acts like this - i will mark it as the answer?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in desktop browser, when the parent element has an `overflow: scroll` style, the scrollbar will appear regardless the content is overflowed or not. by setting it to `auto`, the scrollbar will only appear  when the content is really overflowed.

you can refer to this link for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow